# Reddit Browser Buttons iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

Does anyone have any idea on how the developers of the reddit iphone application created the browser buttons which appear in the navigation bar when viewing external sites?

does `rightBarButtonItem` accept any view -> did they just create a view with multiple buttons and assign it to `self.navigation.rightBarButtonItem` or did they subclass `UIButton`?

Is their a standard "multiple button" button implementation?

Answer (score 2):

The `rightBarButtonItem` can contain any view as long as you wrap it in a `UIBarButtonItem`.

For a "multiple button", do you mean a [UISegmentControl](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)?

If there's no title, and you want a UISegmentControl, you should set the control as the title view and leave the right bar button item blank.